# Why does LocalDateTime fails to parse from string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, iso

I wrote following code in Spring

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public StationView getSingleStation(@PathVariable Long id,
                                    @RequestHeader("Authorization") String tokenHeader,
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam LocalDateTime startDate,
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam LocalDateTime endDate)
```

But when i try to send data in format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ (for example 2018-11-27T10:57:43.019+0100)
It does throw exception

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2018-11-27T10:57:43.019 0100'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-11-27T10:57:43.019 0100]]
```

I've noticed that framework removes '+'

I got message: 'Parse attempt failed for value [2018-11-27T10:57:43.019 0100]]'

When I'm passing 2018-11-27T10:57:43.019+0100

Answer (score 3):

Timezones are supported in Java by using `ZonedDateTime` class instead of `LocalDateTime`. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Either modify the method signature (probably with @DateTimeFormat too) or decide not to use timezones in your dates.

Answer (score 0):

> Parse attempt failed for value [2018-11-27T10:57:43.019 0100]

Your string seems to have been URL decoded: the `+` (plus) that was in it has been replaced by a space. Either avoid that, or probably better, URL encode it before sending it so that URL decoding will restore the original string.

amseager may have a point too. I’ll add a bit of precision to it: Since your string contains an offset, `+01:00`, the correct type to use is `OffsetDateTime`. The `ZonedDateTime` class mentioned in the other answer is for when you’ve got a time zone, for example America/Nome. Time zone IDs are in the format *region/city*.